# Alert view for multiple cells of table View in xcode

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

How can I give an alert View for multiple cells in a tableView, so that when I give an alert to a cell in the tableView it will affect all tableView Cells.

Please help me.

Comment: What exactly is the question again ?

Comment: I wanna to display separate alertView in a table view, i given for single cell but the alert view affected whole cells in the tableView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to effect a change for a single cell, you should use the `indexPath` property and determine which row and column you are accessing and use any method that you like.

```
if (indexPath.row ==0) 
       // Show alertView for row 1

if (indexPath.row==5)
       // Show alertView for row 6

else 
  // Don't show anything.
```

This will not affect the whole tableView.

Comment: thank You. But, i have calculations on each cell. we given like this when we selected the cell the alert view will display. i have to get values in each cell. if the getting values for a particular cell is 0 that time only i wanna to display the alert view

Comment: Then go to the `gettingValues()` method and check for `indexPath.row`

Answer (score 0):

Though the question is not very clear, I am assuming that you want to show alert view on tap of tableview cells but you want the alert view to have different message when different cells are tapped.

Create an instance variable to hold an array of messages. Each index should hold a NSString with message corresponding to the respective cell in the table view.

Then in the

`- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

implementation you can check the row number using `indexPath.row`, access the corresponding message from the messages array and show the alert view with that message.

If you want the alert view to show on specific cell tap, then check indexPath.row and show alertview selectively.